# what kind of pubkey is this?

Tags: public-key, eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain

i found a bunch of old pubkeys but i dont remember how i created them or even if they were mine. they seem to be a bit short and i cant convert them to a an actual address
if anyone has any ideea about this

```
0x92a7b7f9602699e142497243721e8cbd56a9ae82dbd401fe4d74cae4874e97cfcbd385fdc467f77c52209656cd7b262c
0xa375b3f837c4c89eed1a8996be1c85284c601497ff22f4684e42350ddac7e48f02e0bfdb2e90abb4e37a5ab68938565c
```

i presume they are pubkeys because they where stored in a file called pubkeys :)

Comment: I tried running them through ethers.utils.computeAddress and it says they are invalid keys.. Are you sure they are ethereum keys?

Comment: i think they are validators address[link]https://beaconscan.com/main/validator/0x92a7b7f9602699e142497243721e8cbd56a9ae82dbd401fe4d74cae4874e97cfcbd385fdc467f77c52209656cd7b262c